# AWS Load balancer

Tags: ssl

Всем привет!

Поднято 2 инстанса windows server c IIS для веб сайтов.
Нужно создать лоад балансер для 2 инстансов. Не могу понять, какой именно создавать. Инстансы созданы в разных зонах. Балансер должен быть с SSL.
Все сайты, которые будут на IIS так же будут HTTPS. Route 53 DNS домена уже перенес на амазон.
Второй вопрос: как использовать SSL сертификат амазона для балансера? при создании сертификата оно просит ввести домен. Какой домен указывать? Просто в будущем планируется иметь домен example.com и сабдомены my1.example.com, my2.example.com и т.д. Видел, что можно зарегистрировать wildcard сертификат на амазоне, но он будет работать только с сервисами амазона. А мне нужно, чтобы каждый сайт на IIS был так же с сертифкатом. Т.е. при создании сайта в IIS нужно будет заливать сертификат и выбирать его

Answer (score 0):

1. Необходимо создать Application Load Balancer.
2. SSL-сертификат необходимо добавить в балансировщик в секцию "SSL Certificate" для listener HTTPS:443.
3. Домен указываете *.example.com, при условии, что ваш сертификат поддерживает сабдломены.
4. На IIS сертификаты устанавливать не нужно.